# How can I use a bat/vbs file to pop up a message just above the notification area?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, vbscript, popups, code

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").PopUp "The CPU is hot.", 5
```

The above is used in a vbs file. The message box will appear in the center of the screen.
Is it possible to make it appear just above the notification area?

Comment: You haven't included `pop-up_message.vbs` :/

Comment: No cmd/vbscript but powershell can show a [notification balloontip](http://techibee.com/powershell/system-tray-pop-up-message-notifications-using-powershell/1865) works nicely in Win10

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it. I had saved the codes there into a ps1 file, but no balloontip appeared when I ran the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By googling, I found the following way to display a balloon tip:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 
$objNotifyIcon.Icon = "D:\folder\image.ico"
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "None" 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "The CPU is hot!" 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Warning"
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True 
$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
```

Save the above in a .ps1 file and use the following in a .bat file to run the .ps1 file.

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file "D:\folder\BalloonTip.ps1"
PING -n 10 LOCALHOST
"D:\folder\NoTrayOrphans.exe"
```

The .bat file can be run without a command window via the following code in a .vbs file:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "D:\folder\BalloonTip.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: what is `"D:\folder\NoTrayOrphans.exe"`?? and, should that line be part of the previous line?